# Run war spring roo 2.0.0 RC1 on wildfly

Tags: spring-roo

I'm having trouble running the .war that the spring roo spawns on wildfly 10
Executing in the roo shell the following command in the creation of the project:
project setup --topLevelPackage com.example --java 8 --packaging WAR

Added path
server.contextPath=/teste

After running:
Mvn package

It generates a .war that can execute using
Java -jar xxxxx-exec.war

It starts correctly and is accessed by the browser.
When I play it in the folder deployments the wildfly does not wheel.
I found that I had to remove the tomcat built-in spring boot:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then add:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I created a new .war and tried to run in wildfly, but it did not run again, not from error or anything, it says it started, but when I try to access the url, it shows forbidden.

Sorry my english, I'm brazilian and I'm using google translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to deploy your Spring Boot application in a `Wildfly` server you need to extend your `@SpringBootApplication` .java class from `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement the `configure` method.

With that simple steps, you will be able to deploy and run your application in tomcat, jboss, wildfly, etc.

To know more about the changes that you should apply, read  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, this was what was missing.
Now it is giving another error, all webjars files are not being loaded, it is giving 404. https://i.imgur.com/sJX6jYc.png

Comment: I do not know why, but using dependency:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
   <version>1.12.3</version>
  </dependency>

With:
"@{/webjars/jquery/dist/jquery.js}"

It gives 404.
However, if I use:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
   <version>1.12.3</version>
  </dependency>

With:
"@{/webjars/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.js}"

It can load the JS. Why using bower does not load?